# Loop list in R and return entropy vector

Tags: r, loops, vector, sapply, entropy

I'm very new to R and new to programing as a whole. I'm trying to loop over a list object and return the entropy (ineq::entropy) of each vector. However when I run my code all it does is print the output of the faultList.

What am I missing here?

```
library(package:ineq)
faultList <- list(asset1 = as.factor(c("engine", "engine", "brakes", "engine", "engine")),
                  asset2 = as.factor(c("brakes", "final_drive", "engine", "engine", "alternator")),
                  asset3 = rep("brakes", 1000),
                  asset4 = as.factor(c("final_drive", "final_drive", "torque_converter", "spark_plug", "engine")))
entropies <- sapply(faultList, ineq::entropy)

for (entropies in faultList) {

  print(c(entropies, na.rm=TRUE))

}
```

Updated my code, swapped `for (entropies in faultList)` to `for (faultList in entropies)`

My new output is:

```
asset1     asset2     asset3     asset4      na.rm 
0.03061904 0.09126107         NA 0.09578598 1.00000000 
    asset1     asset2     asset3     asset4      na.rm 
0.03061904 0.09126107         NA 0.09578598 1.00000000 
    asset1     asset2     asset3     asset4      na.rm 
0.03061904 0.09126107         NA 0.09578598 1.00000000 
    asset1     asset2     asset3     asset4      na.rm 
0.03061904 0.09126107         NA 0.09578598 1.00000000
```

Comment: You are not looping *entropies* but *faultList*. Your loop variable is same as `sapply` assigned object.

Comment: @Parfait What do you mean by the looping. Do I have my variables swapped in the for loop?

Comment: To get the results of sapply you do not need to use a loop. Simply look at the resulting object (entropies). I think it has what you need, since it is a named numeric vector.
If you want to ommit NA just do: na.omit(entropies)

Comment: @JereB I updated my post. Should I remove the loop completely and just do `print(entropies)`? I would need to convert the NA to a 0. Would adding a `na.rm` to the print solve this?

Comment: entropies[is.na(entropies)] = 0.
I don't really understand why you need a print statement. If you want to print to console then just do print(entropies)...

Comment: @JereB I needed to view the vector outputs. That worked! If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @GwinnyJane I added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to replace the NA by a specific value we can index it using a boolean.
This asks R to change only entries that are NA.

```
entropies[is.na(entropies)] = 0
```

To print the results:

```
print(entropies)
```